# How to populate a ComboBox After adding new item

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a SSIS control flow task.  On my UI I have a combobox which displays a list of avaialble user variables as well as the ability add a new variable.  I'm able to add the variable successfully but I can't see it in my combobox even after I repopulate the datasource.  On the SelectionChangeCommitted event I am saving the combobox selection.  If the user selects to add a new SSIS user variable then they are prompted to within this method.  The variable is saved and then I am repopulating the datasource of the combobox.  Although my new variable isn't being shown in the drop down list.  Should I be repopulating the combobox on a different event?

An example of the code I am using below.

```
  private List<string> FillVariablesList()
    {
        List<string> Variables = new List<string>();
        Variables.Add("");
        Variables.Add(New_Variable);
        foreach (Variable v in this.theTaskHost.Variables)
        {
            if (!v.SystemVariable && v.DataType == TypeCode.String)
                Variables.Add(v.Name);
        }

        return Variables;
    }

 combobox.datasource = FillVariablesList();
```

Comment: Its the method above.  It populates a List<string> with variable names and returns the list.  My appologies the method name was wrong in the example above.  I've fixed it.

Comment: are you calling combobox.Databind() anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a shared ObservableCollection like this.

```
... 
class A
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> variables = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    ...
    private void FillVariablesList() 
    {
        variables.Clear();
        variables.Add(""); 
        variables.Add(New_Variable); 

        foreach (Variable v in this.theTaskHost.Variables) 
        { 
            if (!v.SystemVariable && v.DataType == TypeCode.String) 
                variables.Add(v.Name); 
        }

        this.comboBox.DataSource = null;
        this.comboBox.DataSource = variables;
    }
}
```

And you can even setup the FillVariables method so that it just adds the new one rather than clearing it and re-filling - I just don't know how the rest of your code is structured.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll certainly give it a go tomorrow morning.  I've never come across ObservableCollection type before.  Something to investigate.

Comment: I can't find the ObservableCollection type even after referencing the System.Collection.ObjectModel lib in my class. Any ideas?  Never mind I found it.  I wasn't referencing the WindowBase v3 dll in my project.

Comment: I'ved added the above as suggested.  I'm setting the datasource of the comboboxes in the form_load event and I'm filling the variables observablecollection before I assign the datasources to the comboboxes.  When I add a new variable it is being added to the observable collection but the comobox datasource isn't being refreshed.  Should I be reassigning the datasource of the comoboxes as well?

Comment: @zeencat I modified the code for something that worked for me too - let me know what you ended up doing.

Comment: Exactly as you did above.  I nulled the datasource then reapplied it but I used a binding source as well.  i tried to use the Changed Property handler with the oberservable event but couldnt get it so gave up and did it as above.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't get it to respond any other way either.

Comment: Dont applogise, I'm not complaining.  It's been bugging me for ages how to get it to refresh the data from a list.  I'll use this method in future unless I come up with something else. Thanks